# How can I do a conditional SQL insert statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm completely new to MySQL. I'm attempting to write a query that inserts a row into the table, but only if the previous row was inserted over 5 minutes ago. Additionally, I'd like my PHP code to have some way of knowing whether the data was inserted or not. This is my attempt:

```
IF (SELECT max(EntryDate) from MyTable) < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE() INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) THEN
   INSERT INTO MyTable (...) values (...)
ELSE
   Select false
END IF
```

Unfortunately, but not unsurprisingly, that gives a syntax error (the error is being very vague about the location of the problem).

Am I doing something stupid?

Comment: Shouldn't this be something that is handled outside of the db? Sounds like a business rule to me.

Comment: @Matt Phillips: "business rule"? Not sure what you mean. I just don't want to pollute my database with identical data, as the values change very slowly, but the database may be asked to update at an arbitrary time.

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE` returns the date as of midnight -- subtracting five minutes will give you a time of 23:55:00 for the previous day.  Also, there's a typo - there should be a comma between `CURRENT_DATE()` and `INTERVAL`.  Seeing the error message would help.

Comment: Ooh, I actually wanted the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. My bad. The error message was useless: "Syntax error somewhere near [entire query goes here]", so I thought I'd omit it.

Comment: It's not useless, because it tells where the error was encountered.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: It is useless, because it only tells me that my MySQL syntax error is somewhere (unspecified) within my query. Well where else would it be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [WHERE NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) and check for a row with `>` time-5 minutes.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (column1, column2) 
SELECT value1, value2 FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM MyTable 
                  WHERE EntryDate > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE))
```

Comment: You're gonna have to elaborate on that one. I'm not fluent enough in MySQL to see how to use it.

Comment: Eric, I've added to the answer.

Comment: __+1__ Actually, I think I could've worked _that_ out from the documentation, in hindsight. Thanks anyway. As for the second part of my question, is there an easy way for my PHP code to determine whether the `INSERT` was successful?

Comment: Sure. Just call `mysql_affected_rows` right after (assuming you're using the mysql_* functions). http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Comment: Is this better or worse practise than [@Dan Grossman's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168734/how-can-i-do-a-conditional-sql-insert-statement/4168771#4168771)?

Answer (score 4):

You run the SELECT query, look at the result in your program, then decide whether to run the INSERT query.

```
//Ask for how many rows are less than 5 minutes old
$count = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE MAX(EntryDate) > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE"),0);
if ($count == 0) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO...");
    //I know I just INSERTed a row because I'm inside the conditional!
}
```

Comment: I thought about doing that. Are there any performance differences? Also, I noticed that you didn't use `DATE_SUB()`, and used a minus: Does that actually work?

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I get an "Invalid use of group function" error, again, with no location.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about MySQL syntax, but you might need to wrap parentheses around this part:
`(SELECT max(EntryDate) from MyTable) < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE() INTERVAL 5 MINUTE`